# Retrieving values from multiple Excel files

Tags: python, excel, tkinter, dialog

I'm attempting to read values from multiple Excel files with the following function:

```
def uploadtranscipt(self):

    self.student=[]
    self.transcript_upload = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=(("Excel files", ".xls"), ("All files", "*.*")),multiple=1)
    self.student.append(self.transcript_upload)
    self.book = xlrd.open_workbook(str(self.transcript_upload))
    self.sheet = self.book.sheet_by_index(0)
    for i in self.student:
        for stu in i :
            self.id = (self.sheet.cell(0,0).value).encode("utf-8")
            print self.id
            self.name = (self.sheet.cell (0,1).value).encode("utf-8")
            print self.name
            self.dep = (self.sheet.cell(0, 2).value).encode("utf-8")
            print self.dep
            self.gpa = self.sheet.cell(0, 3).value
            print self.gpa
```

However, the following Exception is raised:

> IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or filename: "(u'C:/Users/r.la/Desktop/programming 2/Transcripts/Sample27.xls', u'C:/Users/r.la/Desktop/programming 2/Transcripts/Sample26.xls')"

Comment: that's just a dump of code and an error message. It should be a programming question, instead. So, please, what is your question? what do you want to do?

Comment: i want to take the values from more than one excel file but it gives me this error when i select more than file

Answer (score 0):

`tkFileDialog.askopenfilename` returns a tuple of filenames. However, `xlrd.open_workbook` only takes a single filename to open.
If you want to read data from multiple files, use a `for` loop to process one file at a time:

```
def uploadtranscript(self):

    self.student=[]
    self.transcript_upload = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=(("Excel files", ".xls"), ("All files", "*.*")),multiple=1)
    self.student.append(self.transcript_upload)
    for transcript_fname in self.transcript_upload:
        self.book = xlrd.open_workbook(transcript_fname)
        self.sheet = self.book.sheet_by_index(0)
        for i in self.student:
            for stu in i:
                self.id = (self.sheet.cell(0,0).value).encode("utf-8")
                print self.id
                self.name = (self.sheet.cell (0,1).value).encode("utf-8")
                print self.name
                self.dep = (self.sheet.cell(0, 2).value).encode("utf-8")
                print self.dep
                self.gpa = self.sheet.cell(0, 3).value
                print self.gpa
```